# Form span population when browser is navigated back to form

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am using asp.net core 2.1 and bootstrap 4.1, I have a form with an input as follows:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="FormFile"></label><br />
    <div class="custom-file">
        <input asp-for="FormFile" type="file" class="custom-file-input">
        <span class="custom-file-label text-truncate">Choose file</span>
    </div>
    <span asp-validation-for="FormFile" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

I use JavaScript to bind to the `change` event on the `input` element that's triggered when a user selects a file and then set the `span` value.

When the form is submitted, server side validations are performed and the users browser is redirected to a new page which provides insight into how the file must be corrected if necessary. Users keep the file open and iteratively make changes as needed then save. They navigate back to the form and simply click submit.

The problem is the span is no longer populated with the previously set value, however the form is aware of the selected file (a mouse over raises a popup with the value).

How can I detect this scenario and repopulate the span?

Answer (score 0):

The original code was executed at document load through

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () { /**/ });
```

so inserting another call within the above to reexecute the same code on `pageshow` as such solved it:

```
window.addEventListener("pageshow", function () { /**/ });
```